# Pandas Dataframe filter rows by only one column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to filter a dataframe by only keeping the rows that conform with a regex pattern in a given column. The example in the documentation only filters by looking for that regex in every column in the dataframe ([documentation to filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html))

So how can i change the following example

```
df.filter(regex='^[\d]*', axis=0)
```

to something like this: (Which only looks for the regex in the specified column)

```
df.filter(column='column_name', regex='^[\d]*', axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [vectorized string method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods) `contains()` or `match()` - see [Testing for Strings that Match or Contain a Pattern](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern):

```
df[df.column_name.str.contains('^\d+')]
```

or

```
df[df.column_name.str.match('\d+')]    # Matches only start of the string
```

Note that I removed superfluous brackets (`[]`), and replaced `*` with `+`, because the `\d*` will *always match* as it matches a *zero* occurrences, too (so called a *zero-length match*.)

Answer (score 2):

Filter the DataFrame using a Boolean mask made from the given column and regex pattern as follows:
  `df[df.column_name.str.contains('^[\d]*', regex=True)]`